# KeyError while populating a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

I essentially need a dictionary of dictionaries in the following format:

```
cable_footage = {"AER": {144: len1, 48: len2, 24: len3}, "UG": {144: len1, 48: len2, 24: len3}}
```

This code is what I have so far:

```
cable_footage = defaultdict(dict)
    for placement in ("AER", "UG"):
        for size in (144, 48, 24):
            cable_footage[placement][size] = 0.0
    for cable in adss_layer.features:
        if cable.data["Placement"] == "AER":
            if cable.data["Size"] == 144:
                cable_footage["AER"][144] += cable.data["Length"]
            if cable.data["Size"] == 48:
                cable_footage["AER"][48] += cable.data["Length"]
        if cable.data["Placement"] == "UG":
            if cable.data["Size"] == 144:
                cable_footage["UG"][144] += cable.data["Length"]
            if cable.data["Size"] == 48:
                cable_footage["UG"][48] += cable.data["Length"]
```

However, I want to be able to simplify/generalise it in this manner as the above code is long and non-Pythonic:

```
for cable in adss_layer.features:
    cable_footage[cable.data["Placement"]][cable.data["Size"]] += cable.data["Length"]
```

But it raises a KeyError. How do I overcome this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to populate `cable_footage` dynamically, it should be defined as nested `defaultdict` (`defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s).

Try this out:

```
cable_footage = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float)))
```

Then, inside you nested loop just populate it:

```
cable_footage[cable.data["Placement"]][cable.data["Size"]] += cable.data["Length"]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! But could you explain the logic behind the lambda?

Comment: @AnushreeUmesh A `defaultdict` takes as a parameter a function to create a default value if the key doesn't exist.  Since the value of the outer dictionary is a dictionary that needs default values of floats, you have to use `lamdba: defaultdict(float)`, which is an anonymous function that returns a dictionary with a float default.  Without the lambda, `defaultdict(float)` is an actual dictionary object, not a function as required.